# Speed Control of Brushless DC Motor

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, motor

I cannot understand the code of controlling the speed of brushless dc motor using ESP8266 WiFi Module.

I found it in- https://ubidots.com/blog/speed-control-for-brushless-motors-with-an-esp8266-2/

The part that I cannot understand is-

```
float btof(byte * payload, unsigned int length) {

  char * demo = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

    demo[i] = payload[i];

  }

float value = atof(demo);

  free(demo);

  return value;
}

// Callback to handle subscription

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) 

{

    value = btof(payload, length);

      value = map(value, 0, 1023, 0, 180); 

//Map the 0-100 values from the slider to the 0-180 to use the servo lib.

 ESC.write(value); 

//Send the value (PWM) to the ESC

}
```

Please help me with the code!

Comment: What aspect of the code cannot you understand?  Without being specific, it is hard to help you.

Comment: The entire btof and callback function that have been created. Why have they been created, what is payload and length, why are we creating btof and callback function, what is the logic behind it and how are they related to speed control of brushless dc motor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Callback function` must be data send from server to the ESP.
2. `Payload` is the data byte sent from server.
3. `Length` is the size of data in bytes.
4. `BTOF` is basically byte to float converter which converts all the data byte received into single floating variable and return that floating point value.
5. `ECS.write` must be the function that write the value to the servo motor controller H-bridge IC. It belongs to servo library.
6. Value range that can be mapped into this ECS.write is between 0-180 so `map` function will use that will convert the `floating point data` received from `btof` function.
7. Basic definition of `map()` function:

`Map function` maps a number from one range to another. That is, a value of fromLow would get mapped to toLow, a value of fromHigh to toHigh, values in-between to values in-between, etc.

Does not constrain values to within the range, because out-of-range values are sometimes intended and useful. The constrain() function may be used either before or after this function, if limits to the ranges are desired.

Note that the "lower bounds" of either range may be larger or smaller than the "upper bounds" so the map() function may be used to reverse a range of numbers.

Syntax:

```
map(value, fromLow, fromHigh, toLow, toHigh)
```

Then `ECS.write(value)` will write that mapped value to servor motor controller H-Bridge.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for clearing most of it. Still I have few doubts- 1)`char * demo = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);` Meaning of this line.   2) Is payload a defined function? Which library does it belong to?  (3) Also I would want to know about the subscribe function and client there in the code- `client.begin(callback);
  client.ubidotsSubscribe(DEVICE_LABEL, VARIABLE);`

Comment: In that case you need share your full sketch here. 1.` char * demo = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);` **Meaning of this line**. You should clear your basic C concepts. In this you are assigning some memory space to this char pointer of 10 bytes size;

Comment: The full sketch is here in the link- https://ubidots.com/blog/speed-control-for-brushless-motors-with-an-esp8266-2/

Comment: Payload is a array pointer of byte type. It is declared in ESP8266 Library. Rest is features of TCP communication protocol. You should study about how TCp protocol works. Client Sever concept, what is publish and subscribe, and HTTP Post and Get request. Then you will know about these functions better.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!!

Comment: It would be great of your sir if you can also please provide some useful resources for the same if you have any?

Comment: this is a simple document that tells about esp8266 and contain reference links to other protocols a well [document](https://tttapa.github.io/ESP8266/Chap05%20-%20Network%20Protocols.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for helping out! :)